# how to use javascript to send data to java server

Tags: java, javascript, port

I am wondering how I would go about, or even if it is possible, to send data to a java server via javascipt in the browser. What I would like to achieve is something similar to this:

- Java opens a port and listens for input.
- On my website someone clicks a button and a string is sent to the server.
- The server handles (logs, prints, etc) the sent string.

I am able to set up the java server, step two is what I need help with.

Thankyou.

Comment: What's your exact question?

Comment: Are you using Javascript to prevent the Page Refresh on submit? If so, use AJAX instead.

Comment: Basically I want to send data with javascript to (myIp:8000) so it can be read by a java server that I have created.

Comment: No, Javascript cannot send data to server without the help from AJAX (in this case, JSP as data communication bridge)..

Comment: Why don't you just use a POST request?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp

I suggest to use HTTP POST||GET Request for the beginning. Open port 80 on your machine for this.